# SCfigure + subfigures

Tags: subfloats

My naive idea was to put three figures on top of each other and put
the caption left to it. Now it seems to be impossible, any idea how to achieve this? My errorous code until now:

```
\begin{SCfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
         \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{pic1} 
         \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}
         \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{pic1} 
         \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}
         \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{pic1} 
         \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{some pretty text}
\end{SCfigure}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `floatrow` package. It defines a `subfloatrow` environment.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using two simple side-by-side `minipage`s; one for the caption and the other one for the subfigures. To easily fine tune the vertical alignment of the caption you can use the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package:

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\caption{this is a figure with three subfigures and a long caption for the example. The caption will span several lines for the example}
\end{minipage}}%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{test subfigure one}
  \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{test subfigure two}
  \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-c}
  \caption{test subfigure three}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Simply changing `valign=t` to `valign=b` in the `\adjustbox` commands, you get:

[image]

and with `valign=c`:

[image]

By the way, the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package has a mandatory argument specifying the width, so you should use

```
\begin{subfigure}{<length>}
...
\end{subfigure}
```